# how to show archive only for particular category

Tags: wordpress

in my wordpres have many category ( blog, gallery, review, carrer, profile) now i want to show  in my blog page one widgets (custome widgets or hard code anyhow) only blog category month list and if i click month then show only blog category not other category. i can able to show only blog month by using plugins but if i click month then show all post from other category to. guys can you suggestion me how i can i do that. i am googling but not get any proper solution yet. see attached file my archive list. it could be widgets or hard code in template page no problem [image: blog archive]

Answer (score 0):

> **perticular category archive file.**

```
copy archive.php and rename with category-$slug.php otherwise category-$id.php 
and change code in your archive file.

$slug  = yourcategory slug name
$id    = your category id
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @ravi patel ... you may be mean custom category template. which i made already for my blog page. category-blog.php  ... but i want when i click say June 2013 then show only blog category June 2013 post. right now if i click then open /?m=201306 this mean its open archive.php file. so all i want when archiver open then show my  blog category post only and on my attached screenshot under ARCHIVE show only blog category month